# why does android emulator are keep increasing "Size on Disk"?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator

I wonder why my emulator keep increasing its size on disk. Otherwise it running slower than first time. Is there any solution? I don't want my emulator to save its state too. How to do this?

[image: It's now 14GB]

Comment: Are you seeing this on a real device?  If not, its an emulator.  Wipe it and reinstall.

Comment: Yes. It's emulator. After wipe, the size on disk is decrease but it keep increase again while I am using it.

Comment: Yes, I am also very much frustrated about this issue since long time. everyday it increases 500MB to 1 GB. Due to limited storage in my macbook, I have to do Wipe data of simulator every week.

Answer (score 3):

I found that deleting the test apps from the emulator phone from Settings > Storage > Free Up Space to resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might have set up big emulator storage and SDcard. When the storage is initially empty it does not take space. When you write data on the storage it starts taking also space on the real disk. From my small experience- it can only grow unless you perform manual cleanup. Same happens also with other virtualizations.

The good news is that it will grow to a certain size and not infinitely.

Check "Show on disk" from the AVD Manager to see which files are largest. Size on disk is not same as the virtual size shown in AWD.

Some of my VMs show 9 GB in AVD but only 3 GB in Explorer.

Comment: But the debug connection lost frequently when it touched a certain size. So I have to delete it and create a new one to make my debug session alive as long as I need.

Comment: ok. but how can i set its limitation on its size?

Comment: I think that, at the initial virtual machine setup, there was option to change the size, but this will restrict the maximum size even for temporary storage. You might need to add/remove temporary SD-cards.